# Lambda expression with AND operator in lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I get an error (

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

) when i try to do the database operation, i can't seem to find what's wrong, must be something from this `p.ADRESA.Equals(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()` because without it the code works but i need two conditions, please help

```
 Int16 idValoare =Convert.ToInt16 (comboBoxIDValoare.SelectedItem.ToString());

        if (selectedTabel.Equals("CUSTOMER"))
        {
            if (selectedColoana.Equals("ADRESA"))
            {
                CUSTOMER customer = db.CUSTOMERs.First(p => (p.CUSTOMERID == idValoare) && (p.ADRESA.Equals(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())));
                customer.ADRESA = textBoxValoare.Text;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging and checking the values?

Comment: my psychic debugging powers tell me that listBox1 has no item selected.

Comment: listBox1.SelectedItem is probably null

Comment: Besides `SelectedItem` could be null, `Equals` could also throw a `NullReferenceException` if for example `p.ADRESA` is `null`. You could consider using the `==` operator instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `ToString()` in LINQ method, but you can try this:

```
string selectedItem = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
CUSTOMER customer = db.CUSTOMERs.First(p => (p.CUSTOMERID == idValoare) && (p.ADRESA.Equals(selectedItem)));
```

I hope that helps you. Please feedback.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your `listbox1` doesn't have a selected item. You should really add an extra conditional to perform that check **before** you do any of your code.

Simply:

```
if (listbox1.SelectedItem == null)
{
    //get the hell out of here
}
else
{
   //do your stuff
}
```

Comment: I checked the SelectedItem is not null :|

Comment: at this line 
CUSTOMER customer = db.CUSTOMERs.First(p => (p.CUSTOMERID == idValoare) && (p.ADRESA.Equals(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString())));

Comment: CUSTOMER customer = db.CUSTOMERs.First(p => (p.CUSTOMERID == idValoare)); works fine

Comment: Can `ADRESA` be null in your database?

Comment: in debugger it says : 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll

Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @guNNer2bad You could put it into a (string) variable first and use that variable in your expression.